# How can I access server localhost ports via OpenVPN connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN up and running on a server and serving as a gateway to the internet for private browsing.

I also have several apps running on the same server that I would like to access only via OpenVPN.

For example, if I have etherpad active on port 127.0.0.1:8000 on my server, how do I access that website through my OpenVPN connection on my client? Please let me know what setting changes from the standard configurations are required.

Thank you. I have read many OpenVPN posts and have not been able to understand how to do this...and it seems like it should be simple.

Comment: All posts about "how do I access my localhost over LAN" apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case you would want to allow the port on all interfaces, then use a firewall to drop all connections on that port except through the VPN IP range (and localhost)

If you can get it to work, the rule would be something like

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i tun+ -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

(The tun+ bit means any tun devices)

In order for this to work, you will probably also need to have 2 other things set -

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: I’m quite sure this wouldn’t work. Packages on `lo` cannot come from anywhere but `127/8` (or `::1/128`). A proxy will definitely work though.

Comment: @DanielB Well, we were both partially correct - the rule I put in will work, however it does, of-course, require ip_forwarding be enabled (which I forgot to mention), and also requires the sysctl call to treat 127.0.0.1 as it would any other address.   (I've tested it now that I'm home - and I learnt something today as well !)